# Invalid link on the jQuery tag wiki information page

Tags: support

When I visit [the jQuery tag wiki's info, *Popular plugins* section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) I find the Cycle 2 link, `https://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2`, which is invalid.

[image: Screenshot of the 404 Not Found error.]

The plugin site hosts without, SSL so the valid URL is `http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/`. I didn't find a way to change the URL, so can a higher-privilege user edit and change `https` to `http` in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the tag wiki you link to, you'll find this button.

[image: Screenshot of _Edit Tag Info_ button.]

Click it, modify the link, wait until other users with 5k+ reputation have approved your edit. You can edit without review once you hit 20k reputation and become a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it and edit the link.

Comment: And I think one user to approve it is @Justastudent

Comment: @Shree To be sure, I've double checked across all tags, and all references to .malsup.com are in http nowadays: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1055716/tag-wikis-with-malsup-com-links